# AWS - how on AWS to best to implement OAuth 2.0 web-app flow to access a custom API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, oauth-2.0

I've had a custom API built on AWS and want to secure it so that it is only accessible after completing an OAuth 2.0 web-app flow.  Question is - what services within AWS are used/combined to deliver this sort of API security and Identity management/verification?

Ive not developed on AWS so totally naive as to where to start to answer such a question.

Any pointers are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AWS Cognito to authenticate access to AWS API Gateway:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Using custom Lambda authorizer would be also an option:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-aws-lambda-authorizers-with-a-third-party-identity-provider-to-secure-amazon-api-gateway-rest-apis/

Comment: custom lambda authorizer has not access to the request body, so it might depend on your requirements for your api. I for example had to write the authorizer as a middleware wrapping my handler just because i had logic in the authorizer that depended on the request body

Comment: @Oygen87 As far as I know, Auth2.0 Framework does not recommend sending authorization data in the body. While there are existing implementations, the most common way is to include parameters in the header.

Comment: Your correct, but in my case i had to dispatch some actions depending on if request was authorized or not, and I needed the request body before dispatching those actions. maybe i could have solved it with an authorizer, but i felt it didnt suit me then.